# Model renderer not working in Minecraft Forge

Tags: minecraft, renderer, 3d-model, minecraft-forge

I'm attempting to create a Minecraft mod with Minecraft Forge for Minecraft 1.8 (recommended version), but the model renderer isn't working.

[image]

CustomItem is rendering as a classic purple and black block.

[image]

Inside `public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)`:

```
if (event.getSide() == Side.CLIENT) {
    RenderItem renderItem = Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem();

    renderItem.getItemModelMesher().register(ItemManager.customItem, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(this.MODID + ":" + ItemManager.customItem.name, "inventory"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be encountering a problem specific to Eclipse where textures are not copied to the project's `bin` folder by default. According to [the Minecraft Forge wiki](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Eclipse#Fixing_textures_not_being_copied), try:

> 1. Make a folder in `mcp/` named `res`, place your textures here under `mods/[mod name]/textures`. Edit: as of 1.6.1, the folder should be "assets" instead of "mods"
> 2. Right click the project in the package explorer, select **New** > **Folder**
> 3. Select `Minecraft/lib` as parent folder and Click the advanced button
> 4. Select `Link to alternate location` and select the folder you created, create the link
> 5. Right click the newly created link, select **Build Path** > **Use as Source Folder**